# Can't connect to SQL Server with my vb.net program

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to test SQL Server (I've never used before), and I always get this annoying error:

[image]

I've traveled multiple websites, multiple questions, and do not get the solution. The user 'MrDan' is like the WINDOWS admin... I can't understand why can't connect.

```
Dim con As New MySqlConnection("Server=********;Database=PruebaMultiple;User Id=MrDan;Password=*****;")
```

Am I missing something? Or am I using a bad connection string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, connections to SQL Server are made using `SqlConnection`, not `MySqlConnection`. MySQL and SQL Server are different database systems. Second, explicit credentials work only for SQL accounts. You're trying to log in with a Windows user, and should therefore use `Integrated Security=SSPI` in your connection string (and omit user name and password). To sum up:

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection("Server=********;Database=PruebaMultiple;Integrated Security=SSPI")
```